# How to return values from an inline function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, inline

I have the following script:

```
im = imagesc(anImage, 'parent', gca); 
set(im,'HitTest','off');
set(gca,'buttondownfcn', @someFunction)
```

My problem is that I want `someFunction` to return some values, but I am not sure how to do it in THIS particular scenario. It seems like the inline-ness is not letting me do this...

Thanks.

Comment: Return it *where*?

Comment: @excaza Basically, I just want it returned to my workspace..., so that I can manipulate it in the next line of the program.

Comment: In the code that you have written `@someFunction` is a function handle that you provide as an input to the function `set`. To use it as a function in the workspace, you can explicitly assign it to a variable `>> myHdlFunction = @someFunction` and then use it as `>> myHdlFunction(input1, input2)` (obviously, replace `input1` and `input2` by the appropriate inputs). Function handles are described in MATLAB [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `someFunction()` set a value in your base workspace (I assume that is what you want to achieve), you can use the [`assignin()`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) function.

An example for `someFunction()` that sets the variable `axes_position` to the the current axes' position is the following

```
function someFunction(hObject, event)
assignin('base', 'axes_position', get(hObject, 'Position'));
```

Have a look at the axis and figure properties pages in the MATLAB user guide on how to deal with user UI input in axes and figure controls (not enough reputation to add two more links).

However, you mention that you want to *manipulate it in the next line of the program*. If I understand correctly, this is what the [`guidata`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) function is meant for: *"store or retrieve UI data"*.

Comment: Thank you. I had figured it out later on, but your answers nicely encapsulates the process. Thanks again! :)